# Dynamically increase textarea and change position div

Tags: html, css

Is possible decrease class="Content" when textarea increasing?

```js
$('textarea').on({input: function(){
    var totalHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) - parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
    $(this).css({'height':totalHeight});
}
});
```

```css
.OuterDiv
{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
  }
.Content
{
  width:200px;
  max-height:250px;
  background-color:grey;
  overflow:auto;
  }
.text
{
  resize:none;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:194px;
  min-height:43px;
  max-height:145px;
  background-color:rgba(250, 120, 30,1);
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:Arial;
  overflow:auto;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <div class="Content">Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym. Spopularyzował się w latach 60. XX w. wraz z publikacją arkuszy Letrasetu, zawierających fragmenty Lorem Ipsum, a ostatnio z zawierającym różne wersje Lorem Ipsum oprogramowaniem przeznaczonym do realizacji druków na komputerach osobistych, jak Aldus PageMaker
   
   </div>
   <textarea class="text" placeholder="Write some text..."></textarea>
 </div>
```

Is possible dynamically increase to up height textarea and once decrease class="Content" (make scroll bar in class="Content")

Comment: You want to increase height of text area and decrease content height but add scroll bar to it

Comment: yes, I want increase height of text area and decrease content height

Comment: if you increase the height of text area and decrease content's height ,itext box would overflow and comes out of content box

Comment: Dynamically *how*? Dynamically means "based on a potentially changing condition", however you didn't specify any sort of condition to be met. If you want the textarea to grow along with what's typed, this cannot be done with CSS - you must use javascript. For a jQuery solution, you could do something like: `$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  $(this).outerHeight(this.scrollHeight);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
    $(this).outerHeight(0); // reset height to reinitialize scrollHeight
    var scrollHeight = parseInt($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
    $(this).height(scrollHeight);
    $(this).prev('.Content').outerHeight(300 - $(this).outerHeight());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/81vuv33j/

(I have simplified the CSS a bit since there seems to be a lot of non relevant data for this question. Let me know if I have missed something relevant)

**jQuery Docs:**

- [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)
- [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)
- [.innerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)

Comment: Thank you, I tried do it in css, but I guss that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what exactly you are looking for

From what i understand ,this is what i could make

check this snippet

```css
.OuterDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
.Content textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <div class="Content">
    <textarea class="text" placeholder="Write some text...">
      this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text
      this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is
      the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text
      this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is
      the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text
      this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is
      the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text
      this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text this is the text
    </textarea>

  </div>
```

Hope it helps